# Is there any public facing asynchronous APIs?

Tags: api, rabbitmq, amqp, mqtt, stomp

Are there any standards/technologies/examples of **public facing API's** which would exhibit similar patterns to an AMQP/STOMP/MQTT server?

RabbitMQ fits almost perfectly in this setup apart from one big shortcoming, that is its not hardened for public facing. (user/pass or IP authentication the port can still be hammered, etc. There is no ability to set per-user throttling.)

Broadly speaking an API standard or design which would behave similar to SMPP, where by a payload can be sent by a client, it can be processed, then the client would also be able to stream responses from the same server either immediately or batched for later retrieval. Also scalable to 1000+ requests / second.

Comment: It's really confusing what you are asking here. Are you asking for a spec or implementation? Regardless of which it is neither is a good SO post. That being said you might want to look at http://wamp.ws/ . I have no affiliation with the project.

Comment: Spec OR Implementation.Wamp.js is a client side technology which site atop WebSockets. I am looking for a server side (application layer) protocol. Similar to SMPP or AMQP to achieve async version of a sync public API such as RESTful JSON over HTTP. But could maintain an open TCP connection to avoid setup overhead.

Comment: You clearly didn't read what Wamp is. It is not just for client side. People use HTTP for server communication all the time. Wamp is a protocol spec with implementations that support RPC and Pub/Sub while maintaining an open connection (websockets). It just happens that websockets sits on a couple of layers but is still rather efficient. If you are worried about performance than you can just roll your own. Many things can handle 1000 rps so that is not the right thing to ask. The question is how many concurrent connections can the system handle. Really your question is out of scope for SO.

Comment: _You need a central server between all clients Like RabbitMQ for AMQP_. So this is just a sub-protocol sat atop AMQP (or encapsulated into any other protocol layer). Meaning a public facing RabbitMQ server with no per use throttling capabilities again, back to my first question. Just because a system could handle 1000q/s dosnt mean its the most efficient, I could argue that about SMTP, but I wouldnt choose a chatty protocol by choice. (BTW: I don't need reminding that this is not a good SO post, your opinion is noted.). I will still choose to hold out for a more helpful answer.

Comment: AMQP protocol was designed for internal networks where as the websockets protocol is on top of HTTP meaning you can use standard load balancers ie nginx. Most AMQP servers will not scale for millions of simultaneous connections. You really need to add more detail to your question.. like what devices, reliability, and whether you want queue/topic creation as public. Since Javascript and Websockets are becoming ubiquitous your going to be hard set on building some public api on some other protocol. As for throttling thats all middleware crap that many companies have products for.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was more informative.